# Updating content in pages after view loaded

Tags: swift, cell, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I need to update content in my cells. In page 3 I want firstname to appear right after they enter it in page 2. I know it does save automatically from my code when they enter it in page 2, because my debugger shows it. But it won't show in page 3 title before I reload the app.. Why?

This is my code :

```
let cellId = "cellId"
   let pages = [
       Page (title: "Thanks for downloading myapp", body: "Tap on the right side of the screen to continue."),
       Page (title: "Quick registration!  ", body:  "Please enter your first name below."),
       Page(title:"\(String(describing: firstname!))",  body:"Please enter your last name below."),


   ]
```

In page 2 they have a textfield where they write in the first name.
It saves fine, but it doesn't show in page 3`s title before I have reloaded the app.
This is because the pages are created as soon as the view loads. But I need this to update, so that the users doesn't have to close and open the app to see the change.
Any tips? If you need more code to understand and help, let me know!